# Posting jquery appended input boxes to MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

We have a very large form and we are posting the data to mysql using $_POST, but we have 2 complex sections in the form where we need your help.

HTML markup of form

```
<label>Customer Name</label>  
<input type="text" size="50" name="name" />
<label>Education</label>
<input type="text" size="50" name="class" />
<input type="text" size="50" name="board" />
<input type="text" size="50" name="subjects" />
<input type="text" size="50" name="aggregate" />
<label>Payment Plan</label>
     <ul id="fields"></ul>
```

We are appending following to #fields using jquery

```
<li><input type="text" size="30" name="date" /> <input type="text" size="30" name="amount" /> </li>
```

Now we would like your help with the following problems...

1. How to post education details to mysql table? - using php serialise?
2. how to post appended input boxes to mysql's tbl.paymentplan?

Comment: do u want to add new attribute to the table according to dynamic input boxes??

Comment: we just want to post data(date and payment) to mysql table.

Answer (score 0):

If you've populated the fields using jquery (date & amount) and it's on the form, a simple "Submit" button which posts to a PHP page that handles the insert into the database should work fine.

Nothing complex about it. I use jquery to pre-load form data all the time like that.

If you want to avoid doing a postback entirely, and want to do that through jquery as well, you can. Once the data is loaded into the DOM and the form displays it you can do with it what you want.

Comment: thanks for your answer, that would work great if we have only 2 fields of date and amount, but what if user add 10 fields, how to post that data to mysql.

Comment: you're the programmer in charge so you would know which fields to post and what data to send through mysql. In your original question as well as a comment you said "only date and amount". If there are additional fields, it doesn't matter. Because they will be sent through with the form. Your receiving PHP page needs to handle the postback and write them into mysql.

Comment: thanks for reply, we can use posted data, what my question is.. 
how can we post jquery generated  fields and those can be total of 10-20 so should be set input box name as payment[] ? what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm**

- use `mysql_fetch_field` to know all attributes name from your table
- if attribute  does not exist in current table then update table via php like below

> ```
>   mysql_query("ALTER TABLE paymentplan
>     ADD date CHAR(30) AFTER subject,
>     Add payment CHAR(30) AFTER date");
> ```

- and then insert the data the way u want.

Reference

[mysql fetch field](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php)

Comment: This is a suboptimal idea. What is to prevent a malicious user from altering your table structure into oblivion?